# What would happen if Deadpool were injected with Adamantium?

Tags: marvel, deadpool, adamantium

What would happen to Deadpool if Adamantium were to be injected into him, as it was with Wolverine? The only reason Wolverine was still alive, despite Adamantium being poisonous, was because of his regenerating capabilities, and Deadpool has the same capabilities.

Comment: He becomes [this](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11119/111190794/4452605-5804368357-43774.png), which *nobody* wants

Comment: ha ha ha..no not weapon X

Comment: do u know like weapon x...captain america was weapon 1 ...made for destroying wolverine

Comment: I don't see why this should be closed as "primarily opinion-based". An answer will not require speculation. As Jason Baker has pointed out above, Deadpool _has_ been injected with Adamantium at least in films. __Pranav__: if you like, you can edit your question to be phrased like _"Has Deadpool ever been injected Adamantium in comics?"_.

Comment: Although I agree with Gallifreyan, as long as it's worded like this (with Gallifreyan's revised answer, the question is too opinion-based.

Comment: Deadpool survived as a zombie head. I think adamantium would be a child's play for him

Comment: @Gallifreyan: I may be misremembering, but I don’t think Wade Wilson *was* injected with adamantium in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*. He was given the powers of other mutants, and has retractable swords in his arms for some reason, but I think that was it.

Comment: You might want to specify the X-Men movie universe, because Adamantium is not poisonous outside that.  There are people without healing powers with Adamantium in them in the comics.  At least until retcons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probably could have handled an adamantium skeleton just fine, with similar effects as Wolverine's-- he would eventually age due to adamantium poisoning affecting his healing, but it'd be a very slow process.

However, it's unlikely he'd have agreed to the adamantium infusion in the first place. It would reduce his capacity to regenerate, he doesn't need it to do what he does best (he uses regular weapons, not his own body), and he exploits the normal fragility of his skeleton to both humorous and strategic effect-- in *Deadpool* (2016) he cuts off his own hand to escape being handcuffed, with the severed hand permanently giving his captor the middle finger.  This wouldn't have been possible with an adamantium skeleton.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely his bones would be replaced with Adamantium similar to Wolverine. If Deadpool had this operation done he would not however have claws like Wolverine as Wolverine's mutation included the claws in addition to his healing factor.

Answer (score -1):

Following the [film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/) storyline, he *was injected* indeed, but as the Marvel Wikia Fanpage points in this [article](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Adamantium), nothing is mentioned about Wade/Deadpool on the comics.

Comment: In *Deadpool (2016)*, Wade doesn’t get injected with adamantium; it’s [a mutation-activating serum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)#Plot).